# Why does build break with Akka 2.4-SNAPSHOT missing?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have this in my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"
```

When I compile it, it says:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.10;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Why is that? Even in here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html it says it must exist.

In its directory

> sbt-version
>       [info] 0.12.1

In my home user's directory:

```
$ sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to alex (in build file:/Users/alex/)
[info] 0.13.7
```

Even after this `sbt.version=0.12.4`, the error remains.

```
// name := "my_name123"

version := "0.1"

//scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

//resolvers += "typesafe-snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"

scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-optimise") // , "-feature"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "src" / "main" / "scala" )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "src" / "main" / "java" )

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.0" % "test"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must also add the Akka snapshots resolver to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"
```

Comment: Did you `reload` your sbt configuration? If it can't resolve the dependencies, then you're obviously missing resolvers. Perhaps post your entire `build.sbt`.

Comment: Copied that `build.sbt` exactly and it resolves just fine. Are you still using sbt 0.12.4 with that? Or are you using 0.13.7? It's not quite clear.

Comment: sbt 0.12.4..... But the project contains other sub projects, that might be the cause.

Comment: Hmmm maybe. Something doesn't seem right. You should probably be using sbt 0.13.7. Though your error says it can't resolve `akka-actor_2.10;2.4-SNAPSHOT`, sbt 0.12.3 is using scala 2.9 by default (since your scala version is commented out), which would also fail to resolve. Does your error now say it can't resolve `akka-actor_2.9;2.4-SNAPSHOT` ?